# html-pdf runs very slow in firebase cloud functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage, html-pdf, node-html-pdf

I have developed a function that take an one page HTML, convert it to PDF using htmp-pdf package and upload to firebase storage. When I run this function from my pc it takes less than 5 seconds, but when I run it from firebase function it takes up to 6 minutes. This is the code:

```
  pdf.create(estadoCuenta, { orientation: 'portrait', type: 'pdf', timeout: '360000' }).toStream(function(err, stream) {
      console.log('Nombre del archivo generado: ' + file.name);
      stream.pipe(file.createWriteStream({
      metadata: {
      contentType: 'application/pdf',
      metadata: {
          origin: 'created by ...'
          }
      },
      public: true,
      validation: "md5"
      }))
      .on('error', function(err) {
          console.log('error en la carga de archivo: ' + err);
      })
      .on('finish', function() {
              // The file upload is complete.
              let estadoCuentaPDF = file.name.replace('/','%2F');
              console.log('estadoCuentaPDF:' + estadoCuentaPDF);
      });
    });
```

Variable "estadoCuenta" contains the html to convert.

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
  "description": "This is the default fulfillment for a Dialogflow agents using Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "xxx",
  "repository": "https://yyy@bitbucket.org/zzz/www.git",
  "license": "xxx",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "firebase serve --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "-": "0.0.1",
    "@google-cloud/firestore": "^3.7.5",
    "actions-on-google": "^2.10.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dialogflow": "^1.2.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.6.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "envfile": "^6.9.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1",
    "firebase-tools": "^7.4.0",
    "html-pdf": "^2.2.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "node-env-file": "^0.1.8",
    "nodejs-base64": "^1.0.3",
    "nodemailer": "^6.3.0",
    "pg": "^7.18.2",
    "string-similarity": "^3.0.0",
    "twilio": "^3.31.1",
    "unirest": "^0.6.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful for you to include a reproducible example.... the `package.json` so that we may understand which NPM package and the surrounding code. It's curious that your timeout appears to match your "6 minutes". Does the function succeed? How large is the HTML that you're submitting? How large is the PDF? Cloud Functions defaults to a reasonably low memory size (256MB?) and may be a single core (couldn't find immediately). There's also a challenge with global|local scope for instances. All of these may impact throughput.

Comment: Hi, this is my package.json:

Comment: Thanks. I'll find some time tomorrow to try it. This type of task is, in principle, well-suited to Functions. Let's try to determine the constraint before trying App Engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the computational resources assigned to a function can't be comparable with your local device.

The CPU speed on cloud functions is directly proportional to the Memory assigned as is mentioned in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing), please try to set up 2GB Memory to your function.

With more processing resources your function will be faster.

If the function is not responding in an acceptable time for you, the next step is to use another serverless product such as [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard#instance_classes) or [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas) that allows you to set more resources to your application.

These changes will be affect your bill.

Comment: Thank you! My function already have assigned 2GB Memory. I think that the next step is to move to App Engine.

Comment: I solved the issue following your recomendations. I did separate the html to pdf service in a new single purpose cloud function and respose time is now < 2 secs. Thank you!

Comment: @BluepointDeveloper Please, explain how you solved the issue with more details